# libgit2: How to merge and commit after fetch?

Tags: c, libgit2

I've managed to fetch from the remote, and I'm running the code below to get the changes staged in the local master branch.

```
    git_annotated_commit * fetchhead_commit;

    git_annotated_commit_lookup(&fetchhead_commit,
        repo,
        oid
    );                      

    git_merge(repo,&fetchhead_commit,1,NULL,NULL);
```

So now if I use the git command line tool to commit I get an automatic merge commit comment and after I can see that the log is the same as from the remote. I'm trying to obtain the same with libgit but my efforts so far in trying to create a commit of the merge results in the remote history to be lost.

How should I do a "proper" commit of the merged changes in order to preserve the history from the remote?

EDIT: Got a little further by doing a fast forward, but still if there are local commits these are lost after the incoming merge. Local changes are not lost, but staged after the merge and have to be committed again.

You can see my code here: https://github.com/fintechneo/libgit2/blob/master/jsbuild/jslib.c

The merge is happening in the `fetchead_foreach_cb` function which again is called from `jsgitpull`

And for the record this hack does work in the web-browser if anyone wonders what the emscripten stuff is about.

Comment: How are you creating the commit? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I got a little further by doing a fast forward (using git_reference_set_target 
 ). But if I have local changes these commits are lost, and the locally changed files are staged and have to be committed again. See the fetchead_foreach_cb function in  https://github.com/fintechneo/libgit2/blob/master/jsbuild/jslib.c

Comment: Okay, but after you merge, how are you creating the commit? Are you calling `git_commit_create`?

Comment: The typical workflow for pull is to fetch then call `git_merge_analysis` to decide if you need to fast-forward or merge/rebase. If you decide you need to merge then you have to call `git_merge` to set up the working directory and index, resolve conflicts, then commit.

Comment: OK so let's say there's no conflicts, but there have been commits locally that should be merged with the incoming changes. What should that commit look like? I tried a commit like in the jsgitcommit function but then lost the remote history, or if doing a fast forward in between lost the local history. Using git commit from terminal after the merge in the original example works as it should, so my question is still how to write a similar git commit with libgit2?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'jsgitcommit function'. You should create the merge commit with the `git_commit_create` function. I imagine that the confusion is that you have to create the merge commit with two parents. I can add an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the merge commit with `git_commit_create`. The merge commit should have two parents. One is the current HEAD commit. The second is the same annotated commit you merged in `git_merge` (e.g. the fetch head).

Comment: Thanks! My mistake was that I passed in the git_annotated_commit type as parent when using git_commit. I added this to your answer. Feel free to rewrite it, but works for me now.